# Displaying Cells in Columns, then rows in PHP

Tags: php

I have a table that I would like to display 5 columns or 5 cells across before starting the next row.
Example

If I had 25 records they would be displayed in a table 5 columns wide by 5 rows long instead of 25 rows.

Below is my code.

```
<?php require_once('../../Connections/rec.php'); ?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "",  $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
 if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
$theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
}

$theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

switch ($theType) {
case "text":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
  break;    
case "long":
case "int":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
  break;
case "double":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
  break;
case "date":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
  break;
case "defined":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
  break;
}
return $theValue;
}
}

mysql_select_db($database_rec, $rec);
$query_Teams = "SELECT * FROM rec_manager";
$Teams = mysql_query($query_Teams, $rec) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Teams = mysql_fetch_assoc($Teams);
$totalRows_Teams = mysql_num_rows($Teams);
?>

 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
background-color: #000;
}
.Manager {
color: #FFF;
text-align: center;
text-decoration:none
}
a:link
{
color:white;
text-decoration:none

}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<table border="0">

 <?php do { ?>
 <tr>
   <td><img src="<?php echo $row_Teams['Team']; ?>" width="138" height="92" /></td>
</tr> 
 <tr class="Manager">
   <td><a href="mailto:<?php echo $row_Teams['Email']; ?>"><?php echo $row_Teams['First_Name']; ?> <?php echo $row_Teams['Last_Name']; ?></a></td>
 </tr>
 <?php } while ($row_Teams = mysql_fetch_assoc($Teams)); ?>
 </table>
</body>
</html>
<?php
mysql_free_result($Teams);
?>
```

Comment: Once you have an array, the question os no longer about mysql. It's just a PHP loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set a counter and increment it each time through the while loop so you can then close off the row and start a new one when 5 columns have been added - so with your code from above, cut down to simplify the example, it would look something like:

```
$column_count = 1;
echo '<tr>';
do {

    echo '<td>'.$row_Teams['Team'].'</td>';

    if ($column_count < 5) {   

        $column_count++;

    } else {

        echo '</tr><tr>';
        $column_count = 1;
   }

} while ($row_Teams = mysql_fetch_assoc($Teams));

echo '</tr>';
```

If you can't guarantee that you will always have 25 results, or another multiple of 5,  you would want to add something after the loop to add in any extra empty cells needed to complete the last row.

Comment: That is exactly what I am looking for! 5 columns and then start another row. I just explained it poorly. Thank you I will give this a try.