# mySQL pivot results to output to HTML table

Tags: php, html, mysql

By default mySQL `SELECT` will return rows. I want to output these *rows* as *columns* in a `HTML table`. What is the best way to do this?

```
SELECT * FROM table1
```

outputs:

```
id  |  name  |  description
result1,
resutl2,
resutl3,
etc
```

I want:

```
id         |    result1.id         |   result2.id         |   result3.id   
name       |    result1.name       |   result2.name       |   result3.name  
description|    result1.description|   result2.description|   result3.description
```

I'm expecting a mySQL approach but there may be a html or PHP solution which would be easier?

Comment: Unless you want to hack some pl/sql there is no MySQL-approach. I sugget to fetch complete needed datasets and print them with your logic inside application layer.

Comment: see my answer here for one php solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20011018/displaying-cells-in-columns-then-rows-in-php/20013219#20013219